# How can I make a moving sum from a cell in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe looking like this:

| date | P | >60? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 03-31-2020 | 6.8 | 0 |
| 03-30-2020 | 5.0 | 0 |
| 03-29-2020 | 0.0 | 0 |
| 03-28-2020 | 0.0 | 0 |
| 03-27-2020 | 2.0 | 0 |
| 03-26-2020 | 0.0 | 0 |
| **03-25-2020** | **71.0** | **1** |
| 03-24-2020 | 2.0 | 0 |
| 03-23-2020 | 0.0 | 0 |
| 03-22-2020 | 23.8 | 0 |
| 03-21-2020 | 0.0 | 0 |
| 03-20-2020 | 23.8 | 0 |

- Code to reproduce the `dataframe`:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(date = c("03-31-2020", "03-30-2020", "03-29-2020", "03-28-2020", "03-27-2020", "03-26-2020", 
                           "03-25-2020", "03-24-2020", "03-23-2020", "03-22-2020", "03-21-2020", "03-20-2020"),
                  P = c(6.8, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 71.0, 2.0, 0.0, 23.8, 0.0, 23.8),
                  Sup60 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

I want to sum the P values N days befores the P > 60.
For example, the first barrier (number bigger than 60) is the P = 71 on the day 25-03-2020, from that i want to sum the 5 P values before that day, like:

2.0 + 0.0 + 23.8 + 0.0 + 23.8 = **49,6**

It is a kind of moving sum because the concept is similar to a moving average.
Instead of the average of the last 5 values, for example, I want the sum of the last 5 values from a value greater than 60.
How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry but one cannot follow your work. No one knows what you are trying to do apart from yourself. you have to explain what you mean by mobile summation, give an example and the output. etc

Comment: Thank's for the feedback, I will repair the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi firstly we can solve how to calculate a running sum then we do an if_else on this column, as a general rule you always split complex problems into minor solvable problems

```r
library(tidyverse)
df_example <- tibble::tribble(
         ~date,   ~P, ~`>60?`,
  "03-31-2020",  6.8,      0L,
  "03-30-2020",    5,      0L,
  "03-29-2020",    0,      0L,
  "03-28-2020",    0,      0L,
  "03-27-2020",    2,      0L,
  "03-26-2020",    0,      0L,
  "03-25-2020",   71,      1L,
  "03-24-2020",    2,      0L,
  "03-23-2020",    0,      0L,
  "03-22-2020", 23.8,      0L,
  "03-21-2020",    0,      0L,
  "03-20-2020", 23.8,      0L
  )


# lets start by doing a simple running sum

jjj <- df_example |> 
  arrange(date)
  
jjj |> 
  mutate(running_sum = slider::slide_dbl(.x = P,.f = ~ sum(.x),.before = 5,.after = -1)) |> 
  mutate(chosen_sum = if_else(P > 60,running_sum,NA_real_))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 5
#>    date           P `>60?` running_sum chosen_sum
#>    <chr>      <dbl>  <int>       <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1 03-20-2020  23.8      0         0         NA  
#>  2 03-21-2020   0        0        23.8       NA  
#>  3 03-22-2020  23.8      0        23.8       NA  
#>  4 03-23-2020   0        0        47.6       NA  
#>  5 03-24-2020   2        0        47.6       NA  
#>  6 03-25-2020  71        1        49.6       49.6
#>  7 03-26-2020   0        0        96.8       NA  
#>  8 03-27-2020   2        0        96.8       NA  
#>  9 03-28-2020   0        0        75         NA  
#> 10 03-29-2020   0        0        75         NA  
#> 11 03-30-2020   5        0        73         NA  
#> 12 03-31-2020   6.8      0         7         NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me a lot <3